# Highchart Legend labelFormatter not working properly

Tags: highcharts, legend

I want to display brand logo in legend (line chart).

```
 legend: {
      enabled: true,
      useHTML: true,
      labelFormatter: function () {
                console.log(this.userOptions.image)
                return '<img src="' + this.userOptions.image + '" alt="" >';
      }
 },
```

this code working fine but first time legends overlap

Please check this example :

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vijay6512/1r3tfh5b/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't specified width/height for that image. So while rendering, img tag is 0x0 px. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/1r3tfh5b/2/

```
                    labelFormatter: function () {
                        console.log(this.userOptions.image)
                        return '<img style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" src="' + this.userOptions.image + '" alt="" >';
                    }
```